# Navbar mobile not working bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

We had a working site and then for some reason we can't find the bootstrap menu for mobile is not clickable. But the collapse is working.

I am very happy for your answers.

```
<body class="app header-fixed sidebar-fixed aside-menu-fixed aside-menu-hidden">
    <header class="app-header navbar">
        <button class="navbar-toggler mobile-sidebar-toggler d-lg-none" type="button">☰</button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav d-md-down-none">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link navbar-toggler sidebar-toggler" href="#">☰</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </header>

    <div class="app-body">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <nav class="sidebar-nav">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="{% block menu_taskoftheday_active %}{% endblock %}">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/taskoftheday/8"><i class="icon-speedometer"></i> Task of the day</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha256-gL1ibrbVcRIHKlCO5OXOPC/lZz/gpdApgQAzskqqXp8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using two different versions of jQuery? Check out the bottom of your code. There might be a conflict.

Comment: @nikosGatzoulis I removed one of them. But still not working :)
Thanks for your answer! What else could be wrong?

Comment: Try to use a normal version of jQuery and not the slim one. Many functions are not available in the slim version. Let me know if it solves your issue.

Comment: @nikosGatzoulis It didn't work. If you want to check it out I can give you access to the google drive. It's a django project.